# How to load a website from a certain ip?

Tags: networking, dns, ip

I'm on a DNS (that I can't change) that propagates websites slowly (like days before Google's dns) so when I purchase a domain and point it to my web server and load it in my browser, it goes to a different IP then my web host. My question is, is there a way to make my computer load a website from a specified IP address and not the one my dns is telling me to go to?
I am currently running Windows 7 64bit pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, edit the `hosts` file for your OS put the DNS of your website and the IP you want to go to.

[Here is a walk through](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-hosts-file/) for editing your hosts file on Windows 7

Comment: Windows 7 64bit pro